# How do I enter superscript text with Preview's PDF annotation feature?

Tags: pdf, preview

I can add text to existing PDF files with Preview. But how do I enter superscript text like *123m<sup>2</sup>* ?

This normally works by selecting the appropriate menu entry

[image: superscript]

or shortcut, but I don't find such an entry with Preview and the shortcut does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to input Unicode superscripts via the Character Viewer or a text replacement shortcut.  Superscript 2 is U+00B2  ²